# Cross Origin Filter with embedded Jetty

Tags: jetty

I'm trying to get a CrossOriginFilter working with a couple of embedded Jetty servers, both running on our internal network. Both are running servlets, but I need server A's web page to be able to post to server B's servlets. I think I need to add ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN to a CrossOriginFilter but finding out how to do this with an embedded Jetty instance with no web.xml isn't proving to be easy. I get the following error message in the browser when trying to access server b's serlvets

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Im using angularjs to post to the other server's servlets in a controller.

And here is the code for one of the servers (both are pretty much the same)

```
Server server = new Server(httpPort);

ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
resource_handler.setResourceBase("./http/");

ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
handler.addServletWithMapping(ServerPageRoot.class, "/servlet/*");

FilterHolder holder = new FilterHolder(CrossOriginFilter.class);
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,POST,HEAD");
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");

handler.addFilter(holder );

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { resource_handler, handler,new DefaultHandler() });
server.setHandler(handlers);
server.start();
```

Answer (score 11):

A few points:

- Don't use `ServletHandler` naked like that.  The `ServletHandler` is an internal class that `ServletContextHandler` uses.
- The `ServletContextHandler` is what provides the needed `ServletContext` object and state for the various servlets and filters you are using.
- The `ServletContextHandler` also provides a place for the overall Context Path declaration
- The `ServletContextHandler` is also the place for Welcome Files declaration.
- Don't use `ResourceHandler`, when you have `DefaultServlet` available, its far more capable and feature rich.

Example:

```java
Server server = new Server(httpPort);

// Setup the context for servlets
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
// Set the context for all filters and servlets
// Required for the internal servlet & filter ServletContext to be sane
context.setContextPath("/");
// The servlet context is what holds the welcome list 
// (not the ResourceHandler or DefaultServlet)
context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });

// Add a servlet
context.addServlet(ServerPageRoot.class,"/servlet/*");

// Add the filter, and then use the provided FilterHolder to configure it
FilterHolder cors = context.addFilter(CrossOriginFilter.class,"/*",EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,POST,HEAD");
cors.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");

// Use a DefaultServlet to serve static files.
// Alternate Holder technique, prepare then add.
// DefaultServlet should be named 'default'
ServletHolder def = new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class);
def.setInitParameter("resourceBase","./http/");
def.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","false");
context.addServlet(def,"/");

// Create the server level handler list.
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
// Make sure DefaultHandler is last (for error handling reasons)
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { context, new DefaultHandler() });

server.setHandler(handlers);
server.start();
```

Comment: Do you mind updating your answer? Because the code as provided doesn't work (v9.3.4RC0). Firefox tells me `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`

Comment: @joakim-erdfelt I have kind of a meta-question: How does one find out how to approach this solution (except for finding your great answer on SO of course)? I really tried hard to find out myself by reading the Jetty and Servlet documentations, but to no avail. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

managed to get it working by doing

```
FilterHolder holder = new FilterHolder(CrossOriginFilter.class);
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "GET,POST,HEAD");
holder.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
holder.setName("cross-origin");
FilterMapping fm = new FilterMapping();
fm.setFilterName("cross-origin");
fm.setPathSpec("*");
handler.addFilter(holder, fm );
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help someone even though it is not a good answer to the original question. I realized that you can easaly enable cross origin request sharing in an embedded jetty instance by manipulating the headers directly in your handler. The response object below is an instance of HttpServletResponse (which is passed to the handler).

Example:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the way of above answers and other similar ones. But always, I came across same error message.

Finally I reach a correct answer for my situation. I use Jersey with Jetty and I am not using web.xml. If you try all methods and you don't enable the CORS support, maybe you can try this solution below.

1. First, define a filter (you can define another one which directly implements Filter class)

---

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class CorsFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static boolean isPreflightRequest(ContainerRequestContext request) {
        return request.getHeaderString("Origin") != null && request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS");
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {

        // If it's a preflight request, we abort the request 
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            request.abortWith(Response.ok().build());
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {

        // if there is no Origin header, we don't do anything.
        if (request.getHeaderString("Origin") == null) {
            return;
        }

        // If it is a preflight request, then we add all
        // the CORS headers here.
        if (isPreflightRequest(request)) {
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
            response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    // Whatever other non-standard/safe headers (see list above)
                    // you want the client to be able to send to the server,
                    // put it in this list. And remove the ones you don't want.
                    "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization,"
                            + "Accept,Origin,Cache-Control,Accept-Encoding,Access-Control-Request-Headers,"
                            + "Access-Control-Request-Method,Referer,x-csrftoken,ClientKey");
        }

        response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

2. Register this filter to resource config

---

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

public class AppServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server jettyServer = new Server();

        // Add port
        ServerConnector jettyServerConnector = new ServerConnector(jettyServer);
        jettyServerConnector.setPort(Integer.parseInt("9090"));
        jettyServer.addConnector(jettyServerConnector);

        // Define main servlet context handler
        ServletContextHandler jettyServletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
        jettyServletContextHandler.setContextPath("/service");

        // Define main resource (webapi package) support
        ResourceConfig webapiResourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        webapiResourceConfig.packages("com.example.service");
        ServletContainer webapiServletContainer = new ServletContainer(webapiResourceConfig);
        ServletHolder webapiServletHolder = new ServletHolder(webapiServletContainer);
        jettyServletContextHandler.addServlet(webapiServletHolder, "/webapi/*");

        // Add Cors Filter
        webapiResourceConfig.register(CorsFilter.class, 1);

        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            jettyServer.dump(System.err);
            jettyServer.join();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } finally {
            jettyServer.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. This solution solved my problem. Maybe it can be useful for others.

Comment: could you post the full code (includ. starting jetty?)